# Instantiate a subclass from a superclass instance and make it resetable

Tags: python

I have a base class A with some heavy attributes (actually large numpy arrays) that are derived from data given to A's `__init__()` method.

First, I would like to subclass A into a new class B to perform modifications on these attributes with some B's specific methods. As these attributes are quite intensive to obtain, I don't want to instantiate B the same way as A but better use an A instance to initialize a B object. This is a type casting between A and B and I think I should use the `__new__()` method to return a B object.

Second, before every computations on B's attributes, I must be sure that the initial state of B has been restored to the current state of the instance of A that has been used for B instantiation, without creating a B object every time, a kind of dynamic linkage...

Here is an example code I wrote:

```
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data=data

    def generate_derived_attributes(self):
        print "generating derived attributes..."
        self.derived_attributes = data.copy()


class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, obj_a):
        assert isinstance(obj_a, A)
        cls = deepcopy(obj_a)
        cls.__class__ = B
        cls._super_cache = obj_a # This is not a copy... no additional memory required
        return cls

    def compute(self):
        # First reset the state (may use a decorator ?)
        self.reset()

        print "Doing some computations..."


    def reset(self):
        print "\nResetting object to its initial state"
        _super_cache = self._super_cache # For not being destroyed...
        self.__dict__ = deepcopy(self._super_cache.__dict__)
        self._super_cache = _super_cache


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(np.zeros(100000000, dtype=np.float))
    a.generate_derived_attributes()
    print a

    b = B(a)
    print b

    b.compute()

    b.compute()
```

Is this implementation a kind way to reach my objective with python or is there more Pythonic ways... ? Could I be more generic ? (I know that using `__dict__` will not be a good choice in every cases, especially while using `__slots__()`...). Do you think that using a decorator around `B.compute()` would give me more flexibility for using this along with other classes ?

Comment: Any comment on the code is also welcome :)

Comment: I think you should use strategy pattern

Comment: @Ciro I thought the strategy pattern were usefull for choosing algorithm at runtime. I can't manage to see its usage in my particular case. Could you be more precise ?

Comment: Hmm... interesting... Let me try this approach to my problem. Nah, I take it back, this won't help me.